# Non-geometric series of reciprocals of squares that equals a reciprocal of a cube?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I am curious if there are some interesting sums of reciprocals of square integers that equal a reciprocal of a cubed integer besides simply modifying a geometric series.

I first checked to see if I could find a pattern in the infinite sums where the integers that are squared in the denominators increase as slowly as possible. For examples,
$$\frac{1}{2^3}=\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{9^2}+\frac{1}{26^2}+\frac{1}{126^2}+\frac{1}{1036^2}+\cdots
\\\frac{1}{3^3}=\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{11^2}+\frac{1}{32^2}+\frac{1}{235^2}+\frac{1}{2815^2}+\cdots
\\\frac{1}{4^3}=\frac{1}{9^2}+\frac{1}{18^2}+\frac{1}{73^2}+\frac{1}{437^2}+\frac{1}{9012^2}+\cdots
\\\frac{1}{5^3}=\frac{1}{12^2}+\frac{1}{31^2}+\frac{1}{259^2}+\frac{1}{3908^2}+\frac{1}{955662^2}+\cdots
\\\frac{1}{6^3}=\frac{1}{15^2}+\frac{1}{74^2}+\frac{1}{624^2}+\frac{1}{22787^2}+\frac{1}{2691037^2}+\cdots
$$
Is there some pattern in these sequences of numbers? I'm very curious to know.

But also, are there other non-geometric series that equal cube reciprocals and which follow a pattern?

And finally, what about finite series? For $1/4^3$ we can also say
$$\frac{1}{4^3}=\frac{1}{8^2}=\frac{1}{9^2}+\frac{1}{18^2}+\frac{1}{72^2}$$
What similar finite sums exist for other reciprocals of cubes?

Comment: That's [greedy Egyptian decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions) with limitations; I don't think any kind of pattern is known.

Comment: Isn't it trivial that by selecting some terms from the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)$ we may get every number in the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)$?